# How to process a DataRow with C# Linq to group and process data

Tags: c#, linq

I am getting a DataTable from SQL Server using a stored procedure. The following shows a simplified version of the data

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Products");
        dt.Columns.Add("ProductID");
        dt.Columns.Add("CustomerID");
        dt.Columns.Add("CustomerState");
        dt.Columns.Add("CustomerCity");

        // DataRow row1 = table1.NewRow();
        object[] o = { 1, 1, "TX", "Austin" };
        dt.Rows.Add(o);

        object[] o1 = { 2, 2, "AZ", "Phoenix" };
        dt.Rows.Add(o1);

        object[] o2 = { 2, 3, "OK", "Oklahoma" };
        dt.Rows.Add(o2);

        object[] o3 = { 2, 4, "CO", "Denver" };
        dt.Rows.Add(o3);

        object[] o4 = { 3, 1, "TX", "Austin" };
        dt.Rows.Add(o4);
```

I am planning to group the data by `ProductID`. After grouping there should be only one row for each `ProductID`. If there are multiple `ProductID`s, then the others columns should be concatenated delimited by a semicolon as shown here:

| ProductID | CustomerID | CustomerState | CustomerCity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | TX | Austin |
| 2 | 2;3;4 | AZ;OK;CO | Phoenix;Oklahoma;Denver |
| 3 | 1 | TX | Austin |

I think this can't be done by ADO.NET. So I started to use LINQ as shown below. However

```
DataTable dt = ProcessData();//Data is from the above code where the DataTable is created and populated manually

var results = from p in dt.AsEnumerable()
              group p by p.Field<string>("Productid") into g
              select new
                     {
                          productid = g.Key,
                          items = g.ToList(),
                          //customerid = g.Field<string>("customerid"),
                          //customerstate = g.Field<string>("customerstate"),
                          //customercity = g.Field<string>("customercity")
                      };
```

I had to comment out three lines as I am getting the following error:

> CS1929: 'IGrouping<string, DataRow>' doesn't contain a definition for 'Field' and the best extension method overload 'DataRowExtensions.Field(DataRow, DataColumn)' requires a receiver of type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Below code to concatenation based on group in LINQ

```
var results = 
   from p in dt.AsEnumerable()
   group p by p.Field<string>("Productid") into g
   select new
    {
      productid = g.Key,
      customerid = string.Join(",", g.Select(i => i.Field<string>("customerid"))),
      customerstate = string.Join(",", g.Select(i => i.Field<string>("customerstate"))),
       customercity = string.Join(",", g.Select(i => i.Field<string>("customercity"))),
      
     };
```